# Can you access dita map keydef variables from XSL in Dita-ot plugin

Tags: xslt, dita-ot

**I know in dita that one can access a keydef**

```
<map>
    <title>variables</title>
    <keydef keys="keyName"><topicmeta><keywords><keyword>Text API</keyword></keywords></topicmeta></keydef>
</map
```

**with a keyref statement**

```
<keyword keyref="keyName"/>
```

Is it possible to access keydef from an xsl file within a dita-ot pipeline

I tried the following

```
  <xsl:value-of select="//keydef[@keys eq 'keyName']/topicmeta/keywords/keyword/text()"/>
```

and

```
  <xsl:value-of select="keyword[@keyref eq 'copyright']"/>
```

However these do not work.

Regards
Conteh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used following :

```
<xsl:value-of select="$map/*[contains(@class,' mapgroup-d/keydef ') and lower-case(@keys) = ''keyName'']/topicmeta/keywords/keyword/node()"/>
```

where the $map is defined as

```
<xsl:variable name="map" select="//opentopic:map"/>
```

Comment: That works.. I had to add a second slash $map//* perhaps some difference in dita 2.0.1 version?

Comment: dita-ot 3.4.1: does not work... It seems that the $map does not contain the keydef elements at all. Eventually I had success with opening the original .ditamap: `document(/*/@xtrf)//keydef[@keys='keyName']/topicmeta/...`